# NSScrollView setMagnification: centeredAtPoint: a possible bug?

Tags: objective-c, appkit, nsscrollview

I have a NSScrollView and I need to zoom the documentView by mouse (vertical movement) around a focus point (point inside documentView). I used NSScrollView `- (void)setMagnification:(CGFloat)magnification centeredAtPoint:(NSPoint)point`. Magnification is calculated with delta Y of  mouse movement in mouseDown track loop, `point` is mouse location inside documentView on `mouseDown:`. While zooming back and forth (with the same `point`) causes a drift of origin of documentView so when I return to the same point with mouse (point where I started to zoom), actual pixels under the mouse cursor are moved. It looks to me like error in calculation of contentView.bounds.origin of the NSScrollView during `- (void)setMagnification:(CGFloat)magnification centeredAtPoint:(NSPoint)point` call.
Does anybody noticed/fixed this?

Code used to magnify NSScroll documentView with vertical mouse movement:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
{
    CGPoint  focusPoint;
    CGPoint  startMouseLocation;
    CGFloat  startZoom;
}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet OverlayView *overlay;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed: @"your_image_name"];
    self.scrollView.documentView.wantsLayer = YES;
    self.scrollView.documentView.layer.contents = image;
    [self.scrollView.documentView setFrameSize: image.size];
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    self.overlay.testPoint = CGPointIntegral([self.overlay convertPoint: event.locationInWindow fromView: nil]);

    focusPoint = CGPointIntegral([self.scrollView.documentView convertPoint: event.locationInWindow fromView: nil]);
    startMouseLocation = CGPointIntegral(event.locationInWindow);
    startZoom = self.scrollView.magnification;

    [self.scrollView setMagnification: startZoom centeredAtPoint: focusPoint];

        BOOL keepOn = YES;
        NSPoint mouseLoc;

        while (keepOn) {
            event = [self.view.window nextEventMatchingMask: NSEventMaskLeftMouseUp | NSEventMaskLeftMouseDragged];
            mouseLoc = event.locationInWindow;

            switch (event.type) {
                case NSEventTypeLeftMouseDragged:
                {
                    NSInteger y = CGPointIntegral(mouseLoc).y;

                    CGFloat deltaY =  y - startMouseLocation.y;
                    CGFloat zoom = startZoom + deltaY/100.0;
                    [self.scrollView setMagnification: zoom centeredAtPoint: focusPoint];
                }
                break;
                case NSEventTypeLeftMouseUp:
                    keepOn = NO;
                break;
                default:
                        break;
            }
        };

    return;
}

@end
```

Add 2:
yes, I tried to set the focus point in documentView or contentView space, but it has no effect on driffting during zoom. Check this video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zkpg2p53l84s55c/m.mov?dl=0
Orange point is a focus location. After I zoomed-in (dragging up) and zoomed out, image drifted to the left. The delta (distance of image from the focus point) is smaller when focus point is closer to the center of image. I checked all calculations of zoom and focusPoint and it seems to be ok. After couple of zoom-in/out cycles I tried to place the mouse cursor at exact location when zooming started (focusPoint) to get original zoom value, and even the focusPoint and the zoom passed to the `setMagnification:centeredAtPoint:` method were correct (equal to values when zoom started ), image has driffted.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: The `point` argument of `setMagnification:centeredAtPoint:` is in content view space.

Comment: Please, see my Add2 in original post.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimenting, I got it to work by using documentVisibleRect. This is for a "zoom" feature in a simulated pan/tilt/zoom camera:

```
    // Center on the middle of the visible rect.
    NSRect visibleRect = self.scrollView.documentVisibleRect;
    NSPoint centerPoint = NSMakePoint(NSMidX(visibleRect), NSMidY(visibleRect));
    [self.scrollView setMagnification:zoom centeredAtPoint:centerPoint];
```